# wrong encoding for greek characters using multer upload package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, file-upload, multer

When uploading files that characters are in greek letters the uploaded titles are saved as Î ÏÎ¾ ÎÎ±Î¾ & ÎÎ±ÏÏÎ¹Î¼Î¹ÏÎ±Î¯Î¿Î¹

The following is the multer variables from multer inside js:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.originalname);
  }
});
var limits = {
  files: 100,
  fileSize: 50000000
};
var upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, callback) {
    var ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
  if (ext !== '.mp3' && ext !== '.wav' && ext !== '.m4a' && ext !== '.flac' && ext !== '.aac') {
      return callback(new Error('You can only upload audio files.'))
    }
    callback(null, true)
  },
  limits: limits
}).any('file');
```

I found this code `req.files[0].originalname = Buffer.from(req.files[0].originalname, 'latin1').toString('utf-8');` but I couldnt modify my existing code and am receiving errors either from buffer or some other argument.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly tried with the following and it resolved my issue:

```
const utf8Filename = Buffer.from(file.originalname, 'latin1').toString('utf-8');
callback(null, utf8Filename);
```